# Who was "The Chairman" and what was "The Plan"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-adjustment-bureau

In the movie "The Adjustment Bureau", it was never revealed who "The Chairman" was.

1. Was The Chairman **God**? When Norris asked "Are you angel?" Harry said "We have been called that". So this implies they might be God.
2. What was "The plan"? Was it some sort of paper where fortune is written by the God?
3. What was the office of the bureau? Was it heaven?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole movie just depicts a race of powerful beings that guide our daily lives. If you want to call them angels, you could. The producers didn't want to pin them down to 1 culture or religion, to make it more accessible for the broad audience.

As this [interview](http://io9.com/5778984/whos-the-secret-chairman-of-the-adjustment-bureau) shows, any interpretation is valid.

They originally planned for a woman chairman but left that out for suspense. The plan was just what they wanted for humanity, again it can be mapped to anything religious like karma, faith or...

Point is they tried to be culture independent so everyone could enjoy it. Don't try to pin it down to one culture/religion